# Unable to genrate a float window above all other apps including full-sized one using Python with QT

Tags: python, macos, qt

I am currently developing an app using Python for Mac OS and in future this app is going to be modified to run on Windows as well. Python can meet most of my development needs currently.

The problem now is I need to build a pop-up window that stays on top of all other windows including full-sized apps on Mac.The code I used was as the following:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = QWidget()
    window.setWindowTitle("Always on Top Window")
    window.setWindowFlags(window.windowFlags() | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The problem is it only gives me a windows staying on top of others on the desktop. This window cannot show above full-size apps.

I don't have extensive knowledge about QT so I come here for help.